# Odoo Server Error: Element '<t t-name="theme_tutorial.services_page_template">' cannot be located in parent view

Tags: python, odoo

I am running odoo v12.0 on Windows. When following the tutorial on how to ["Create a specific page layout"](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/themes.html#create-a-specific-page-layout), I get an error:

```
"Element '<t t-name="theme_tutorial.services_page_template">' cannot be located in parent view"
```

Can you help me fix that error?

```
Error:
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\NS Works\Code\Odoo\odoo\models.py", line 1108, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "d:\ns works\code\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 345, in _check_xml
    view_def = view.read_combined(['arch'])
  File "d:\ns works\code\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 791, in read_combined
    arch_tree = self.apply_inheritance_specs(arch_tree, view_arch, parent_view['id'])
  File "d:\ns works\code\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 720, in apply_inheritance_specs
    self.raise_view_error(_("Element '%s' cannot be located in parent view") % tag, inherit_id)
  File "d:\ns works\code\odoo\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 548, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Element '`<t t-name="theme_tutorial.services_page_template">'`" cannot be located in parent view
...

    <record id="services_page" model="website.page">
        <field name="name">Services page</field>
        <field name="website_published">True</field>
        <field name="url">/services</field>
        <field name="type">qweb</field>
        <field name="key">theme_tutorial.services_page</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <t t-name="theme_tutorial.services_page_template">
                <t t-call="website.layout">
                    <div id="wrap">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h1>Our Services</h1>
                            <ul class="services">
                                <li>Cloud Hosting</li>
                                <li>Support</li>
                                <li>Unlimited space</li>
                            </ul>

                            <!-- === Snippets' area === -->
                            <div class="oe_structure"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </t>
            </t>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: It'd be helpful to provide a couple more details on what exactly you tried. How can we reproduce your problem?

Comment: i dont know how to fix. i'm newbie.

Comment: try changing `t-name="services_page_template"`

Comment: after change the t-name="services_page_template", i have the same error. i don't know how to debug that. If i use an alternative to create pages using the <template> directive, i get no error. but when access to http://localhost:8069/services showing error: "Internal Server Error"

Comment: i had change <record id="services_page" model="website.page"> to <record id="services_page" model="ir.ui.view"> and  <t t-name="theme_tutorial.services_page_template"> to <t t-name="theme_tutorial.services_page">. after that, update the tem theme. no see error. but when access web by: http://localhos:8069/services showing error: "internal server error"